# Can not getting config params values in api controller Yii2

Tags: php, api, parameters, yii2

I am getting undefined parameter error while calling `Yii::$app->params['status']`

I have created api folder for web services and in this i have `api/controllers/UsersController.php`. I am calling this `Yii::$app->params['status']` in one of the action of this controller but getting undefined error.

This is my `api/config/main.php`

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    //require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
   require(__DIR__ . '/params.php')
    //require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);
return [
     'id' => 'api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
   'bootstrap' => ['log'],
      'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'idParam' => '_api'
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
        'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                $response = $event->sender;
                if ($response->data !== null && Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code')) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                        'data' => $response->data,
                    ];
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                }
            },
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'pbB0NvlmxlWRk7XFCN_7XUC2uvX0vyCD',
        ],
    ],

];

if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
//    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
//    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
}

return $params;
```

This is my `api/web/index.php`

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php');


//require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/twiliophp/Services/Twilio.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
                require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
                // require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
                require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php')
                // require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/aliases.php');

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Also i have defined status in `common\config\params.php` as follows :

```
return [
   //  'bsVersion' => '4.x',
     'bsDependencyEnabled' => 'false',
   'status' => array('1' => 'Active', '0' => 'In-Active')
];
```

Please tell someone when i made mistake.

Comment: try to var_dump Yii::$app->params and check what do you get

Comment: i have var_dump Yii::$app and in this i get blank array of params like this [params]=>array()

Comment: i have also var_dump in main.php $params. In this i get all params value which i have declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your config file.
You're returning the main config object, and few rows later you're returning the params.

Just change your config file as follows:

```
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    //require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
   require(__DIR__ . '/params.php')
    //require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php')
);

$config = [
    'id' => 'api',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Users',
            'enableAutoLogin' => false,
            'idParam' => '_api'
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
        'response' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\Response',
            'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
                $response = $event->sender;
                if ($response->data !== null && Yii::$app->request->get('suppress_response_code')) {
                    $response->data = [
                        'success' => $response->isSuccessful,
                        'data' => $response->data,
                    ];
                    $response->statusCode = 200;
                }
            },
        ],
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'pbB0NvlmxlWRk7XFCN_7XUC2uvX0vyCD',
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params
];
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
//    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
//    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';
}
return $config;
```

Also, this line on the index file is redundant:

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php');
```

Comment: Yes i have get this from this [https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15588]. Thank you for your answer.